# scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object Python

Tags: python, matlab

Following this question [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43021139/edit) I got to the next question.

I have 40 matlab files and I'm implementing a general solution for extracting that info, as each of them has a different internal organization. As soon as I have it I will post here.

But my question is: the solutions given by gg349 and mergen gets me some objects like this:

```
<scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct object at 0x7f368cff3f90>,
```

And I don't know how to deal with those, could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the equivalent of Matlab struct in python. You can access the elements by dot, like `object.value`. An example here. [Complex Matlab struct mat file read by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970785/complex-matlab-struct-mat-file-read-by-python)