# How to extract data from a complex mat and save them to multiply tables

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab.

I want to save a mat to table files. I have a mat file like this. There is 1* 55 struct, which was stored in “data” field.
[the data structure of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCRid.jpg)

I want to save the “track” field in these structs. And my code:

```
data = load('G:/my_file.mat');
my_output_file = 'G:/my_output.txt'

for my_track_data = data.data.track
    writetable(my_track_data, my_output_file)
end
```

But there is a error:

```
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there 55 results.
```

by the way, I can see the Matlab displayed all the results when I type:
'''
data.data.track
'''

All the 55 tables in the "data.data.track"

I tried just save it without a loop:

```
my_track_data = data.data.track
writetable(my_track_data, my_output_file)
```

It only save just the first table.

Comment: `data.data` contains 55 structs. Each of the 55 structs contains a field `track`. What result do you expect of `data.data.track`? Which of the 55 fields do you want to access? You have to choose one.

Comment: I want save 'track' field in each 55 structs to different files with format of txt

Comment: You didn't answer the most important question for this error message: What result do you expect of `data.data.track`? There is no `track` in `data.data`. There are 55 structs in `data.data`.

Comment: I expect it is a list with 55 tables. I can see Matlab display data.data.track. But it return my just one table

Comment: If you expect `data.data.track` to contain 55 tables I don't understand the question. I thought `data.data` contains 55 structs. Why should `data.data.track` also contain 55 structs? It would help if you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please don't post images of text and please add a [mcve] containing a minimal input file as text, not as link. Currently the structure is unclear for me.

Comment: What is a complex mat? Google thinks of [this](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&ei=PSUxYIuZOM3dtAaZmb_wBw&q=complex+mat&oq=complex+mat&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgIIKToICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDUOAcWNguYI4yaABwAHgAgAGJAYgB3wWSAQQxMC4xmAEAoAEBsAEB) and that’s also my first thought. But it makes no sense in your question...

Comment: Never mind. I followed this thread to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970785/complex-matlab-struct-mat-file-read-by-python" to describe it. I tried to use to Python package "Scipy.io" to parse. And it showed me "matlabopaque" object.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab loops do not work as Python loops (i.e. they do not request an iterator from the structure). Therefore, you should use traditional indexing:

```matlab
for i = 1:numel(data.data)
    my_data = data.data(i);
    writetable(my_data.track, my_output_file)
end
```

(In fact, you can use the "iterator style", but the `for` iterates over **columns**, not rows, so the results end up being dependent on the shape of your data and will most likely not be what you want).

Comment: I add braces to the "data.data.track" and it can be looped. Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with `for d = data.data` and `writetable(d.track, my_output_file)`?

Comment: I think ```d``` is still a complex structure. And by using braces like ```{data.data.track}``` can convert it to cell type. The cell type can be looped.

Answer (score -1):

```
data = load('G:/my_file.mat');

# the braces is very important. It can convert 'data.data.track' to cell type for looping
required_data={data.data.track};

for k = 1:length(required_data)
    my_output_file = ['G:/test_' num2str(k) '.txt'];
    temp = requireddata(k);
    tt = cell2table(temp);
    writetable(tt.temp{1, 1}, my_output_file);
end
```